# TypeError: ctx.onCreditChange is not a function angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components. Component A which is the parent and component B which is the child.
Component A looks like this:

A.html

```
    <nb-box [onCreditChange]="onCreditChange"></nb-box>
```

A.ts

```
onCreditChange($event) { console.log($event) }
```

The function from component A is transferred to B.

Component B looks like this

B.html

```
<div class="box">
 <nb-switch  (onChange)="onCreditChange($event)"></nb-switch>

</div>
```

B.ts  (part of this component)

```
import { Component, Input, NgModule, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

export class Box extends BoxBase {
  @Output() onCreditChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()

}
```

I get an error when calling the function

```
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: ctx.onChange is not a function
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn’t this:  [onCreditChange]="onCreditChange" be this:  (onCreditChange)="onCreditChange" ?

Comment: @MikeOne I changed but I get new erroe : This expression is not callable.
  Type 'EventEmitter<any>' has no call signatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PARENT COMPONENT**

**HTML**

```
<nb-box (onCreditChange)="onCreditChange"></nb-box>
```

**TS**

```
onCreditChange($event) { console.log($event) }
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

The error start here, because Output is not a function, it's an object that allow to you to send events to the parent. You need to do a function in child an inside of that function emit with the output object.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
 <nb-switch  (onChange)="onChangeInChild($event)"></nb-switch>

</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input, NgModule, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

export class Box extends BoxBase {
  @Output() onCreditChange = new EventEmitter<any>()

  onChangeInChild(eventObject: any){
      this.onCreditChange.emit(eventObject)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happend to me beacuse the function call in the template was **misspelled**.